# Given $A\cup B = A$, prove $B$ is the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the above statement, i've to prove that $B = \emptyset$

I started by using the theorem for set equality that says.

> Given two sets $A$ and $B$ we have that:
>
> $A = B \iff A \subset B \quad\land\quad B \subset A$

therefore i just plug things in and i got that

$A \cup B \implies x \in A \quad\lor\quad x \in B$

and

$A \cup B = A \iff A \subset A \cup B \quad\land\quad A \cup B \subset A$

After that i got a stuck, its my first time doing this kind of proofs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the statement is false, so it is not surprising you can't prove it. For example if $A=B \neq \emptyset$ then $A\cup B=A$ but $B\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: What if $A=\{x,y\}$ and $B=\{x\}$?

Comment: @Fishbane i don't really understand, can you elaborate more please?

Comment: The statement that is true is that if **for all** $A$ you have $A\cup B = A$, then $B=\varnothing$. But the statement is false if you just have it for a specific $A$. $A\cup B=A$ is equivalent to $B\subseteq A$, not to $B=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Carlos The example I give simply uses the fact that the union of a set with itself doesn't change it, the rest should be fairly simple. Arturo gives perhaps the best way to make the statement you wrote be true and it is possible that you have simply missed the condition that it is true for all $A$.

Comment: $B$ can be any subset of $A$ and the equation will hold.

Answer (score 1):

**What you have given :**

> Prove :
> $ (A\cup B = A) \implies B = \emptyset $

We can not Prove it , that Statement is not true.
Eg Consider :
$A=\{1,2,3\}$
$B=\{1\}$ or $B=\{2,3\}$ or $B=\{1,2,3\}$
In these Cases , $ (A\cup B = A)$ is true but $B = \emptyset $ is not true.

**What you may have been given or what we can Prove :**

> Prove :
> $ (A\cup B = A) \implies (B-A) = \emptyset $

This is true , & we can Prove it , & Intuitively check it.
When you merge 2 Sets , A & B , you get back Set A ,
... that means the Union with Set B did not add new elements to Set A ,
... which means Set B did not have elements which are not in A ,
... which means all elements of Set B are in Set A ,
... which means Set (B-A) , where all the common elements are removed , must have nothing left over ,
... which means Set (B-A) is the EMPTY SET.

**Observation :**

In Natural Numbers , $A+B=A \implies B=0$ , which is not Directly true with Sets.

Answer (score 1):

Can't prove what isn't true.   Counter example.  $A= \mathbb R$ and $B = \mathbb Q$.  Then $A \cup B = \mathbb R \cup \mathbb Q = \mathbb R = A$.  But $B=\mathbb Q$ is certainly not empty.

So it's not true.

But what is true is $A\cup B =A \iff B \subset A$.

Pf: If $A\cup B = A$ then for any $b\in B$ we have $b \in A\cup B = A$ so $b \in A$.  So $B\subset A$.
So $A\cup B = A\implies B\subset A$.

If $B\subset A$ then.... If $x\in A \cup B$ then either $x \in A$ or $x \in B\subset A$.  So either way $x \in A$.  So $A\cup B \subset A$.  And if $a\in A$ then $a \in A\cup B$ so $A \subset A\cup B$.  So $A\cup B = A$.
So $B\subset A \implies A\cup B = A$

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to write "Suppose A is disjoint from B". Then your statement is true and may be readily proven (Do you see how, assuming $A \cap B = \{\}$, that is, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?)?